# Por que este código da error?

Tags: javascript

vi este código y no sé muy bien que significa:

```
 Date.now || (Date.now = function() {
        return (+new Date).getTime();
    });
```

y que además por qué da el error de que le falta un invocador al constructor.

Entonces me gustaría si se me respondiera como sería el código correcto y como funciona sobre todo por la parte de `date.now || (date.now` <= Refiriendome al `||`

Comment: Tendrás más parte del código? Porque así como tal no se puede probar para ver el error que te manda.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has buscado investigado sobre el el código?

Answer (score 1):

Esta generando una especie de polyfill. Si lo escribimos de otra forma igual se ve más fácil.

```
Date.now || (Date.now = function() {
    return (+new Date).getTime();
});

var miliseconds = Date.now()
```

Si `Date.now` existe no evaluará la segunda parte del or (`||`) y por tanto no se modificará nada. Si Date.now no existe (en algunos navegadores no está implementada la función pase a comprobarse la segunda parte del or y por tanto es como si se ejecutara lo siguiente:

```
Date.now = function() {
    return (+new Date).getTime();
};
```

Es decir simplemente crea el método `now` dentro de `Date`.

Una de las cosas curiosas de JS es que permite invocar a una función sin poner los paréntesis cuando es un constructor y se usa `new`. Esto no es una buena práctica y debería ser evitado pero las siguientes dos sentencias serían equivalentes:

```
new Date;
new Date();
```

El `+` como operador unario se usa para convertir (o castear) un valor cualquiera `Number`. Es también un truco algo oscuro que algunas guías recomiendan evitar. Lo lógico hubiera sido llamar a getTime sobre la instancia de `new Date()`, pero en cambio se hace sobre `(+ new Date)` lo que da un error porqué ese `+` está convirtiendo la fecha a `Number`. Otra forma de escribir la función de forma que no de error podría ser:

```
Date.now = function() {
    return new Date().getTime();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

El operador (unario) + es quivalente a convertir la expresión de la parte derecha a número por medio del constructor [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). Por consiguiente, éstas dos instrucciones son equivalentes:

```js
console.info(+new Date);
console.info(Number(new Date));
```

Observa el siguiente ejemplo para que puedas darte cuenta de la coerción que realiza:

```js
console.info(+"123");
console.info(+false);
console.info(+"abc", Number("abc")); // ambos NaN
```

Como puedes ver te retorna el timestamp del momento de la ejecución. El error está en que trata de llamar al método [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) usando el timestamp que es un número.

Un punto curioso que quizás no sepas es que, en JavaScript se puede llamar a una función constructora sin usar los paréntesis **siempre y cuando se use el operador `new`**. Esta forma de llamada es un shortcut para llamar a un constructor sis parámetros. Esto sin embargo, no es considerado una buena práctica; de hecho, si usas un linter como [ESLint](http://eslint.org) te marcará *error* en dicha línea.